# Pronunciation of ss as s and lack of sh?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I've been hearing some British and Irish actors and presenters pronounce *ss* like *s* instead of *sh*, so tissue sounds like *tisyu* rather than *tishu* for example. I also heard someone pronounce *appreSEEate* instead of *appreSHEEate*. Now, I couldn't find much online about this apart from someone saying it's received English, but not much else. Anyone has further explanation or recommended reading on this. Would *assured* follow the same rule since it sounds unnatural to me, or *passion*?

Comment: The OED offers **Appreciate**, v. Brit. /əˈpriːʃɪeɪt/, /əˈpriːsɪeɪt/, U.S. /əˈpriʃiˌeɪt/, /əˈprɪʃiˌeɪt/ -- **Tissue**, n. Brit. /ˈtɪʃuː/, /ˈtɪsjuː/, /ˈtɪʃ(j)uː/, U.S. /ˈtɪʃu/ -- **Passion**, n. Brit. /ˈpaʃn/, U.S. /ˈpæʃən/ -- **Assured** has only the one pronunciation.

Comment: Why would you expect "ss" to be pronounced /ʃ/ ("sh") rather than /s/?

Comment: Are you an AmE speaker? Words that were historically (before the US existed) an 's' sound followed by a 'y' sound tended to become palatalized in the US, eg 'tissue', but didn't as much in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon is explained by a process that encompasses several principle and that is called "*assimilation*".

"Assimilation" is defined as follows in *The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* (3rd edition, 2008).

([]: user LPH's comments)

> (P. 159)  **Coarticulation**
> **1** Speech sounds tend to be influenced by the speech sounds that surround them. **Coarticulation** is the retention of a phonetic feature that was present in a preceding sound, or the anticipation of a feature that will be needed for a following sound. Most ALLOPHONIC variation — though not all — is coarticulatory.
> […]
> **5** For cases where coarticulation is variable , and may result in what sounds like a different phoneme [one speaks of ASSIMILATION (p. 51)].

### Assimilation  (p. 51, 52)

> (p. 51)
> **1** **Assimilation** is a type of COARTICULATION. It is the alteration of a speech sound to make it more similar to its neighbours. In English it mainly affects PLACE OF ARTICULATION.

> (p. 52)
> **5** **Yod coalescence** (or 'coalescent' assimilation) is the process which changes **t** or **d** plus **j** ([yod]) into **tʃ** or **dʃ** respectively. Across word boundaries it may affect phrases involving **you** or **your**.
> **let you out**              **ˌlet ju ˈaʊt** → **ˌletʃ u ˈaʊt**  [no change in AmE]
> **would you try**      **ˌwʊd ju ˈtraɪ** →  **ˌwʊdʒ u ˈtraɪ** [no change in AmE]
> **get your bags**      **ˌget jɔː ˈbægz** →  **ˌgetʃ ɔː ˈbægz** || **ˌget j<sup>ə</sup>r ˈbægz** →  **ˌgetʃ <sup>ə</sup>r ˈbægz** [AmE]
> **6** Within a word, the status of yod coalescence depends on whether the following vowel is SRONG or WEAK.
>
> - Where the vowel is strong, i.e. **uː** or **əʊ**, yod coalescence can frequently be heard in BrE, although not in careful RP. (In AmE there is usually no yod, so the possibility does not arise.)
>   **tune**    **tjuːn** → **tʃuːn**
>   **endure**    **ɪn ˈdjʊə** → **ɪn ˈdʒʊə**
> - Where the vowel is weak, i.e. **u** or  **ə**, assimilation is often variable in BrE, but obligatory in AmE.
>   **factual**    **ˈfækt ju‿əl** →  **ˈfæk tʃu‿əl** [isolated or careful pronunciation: **ˈfækt ju əl →  ˈfæk tʃu əl**; usual: **ˈfækt ju<sup>ə</sup>l** →  **ˈfæk tʃu<sup>ə</sup>l**]
>   **educate**    **ˈed ju keɪt** →  **ˈedʒ u keɪt**

It becomes now possible to understand # 7 in "**Assimilation**", this 7th part being that which explains the phenomenon referred to in the OP.

> **Assimilation, p. 52**
> **7** Historically, a process of yod coalescence is the origin of the **tʃ** used by all speakers in words such as **nature**, and otf the **dʒ** in words such as **soldier**. Similarly, yod coalescence involving fricatives (**sj → ʃ, zj → ʒ**) explains the **ʃ** in words such as **pressure, delicious, patient, Russian**, and the **ʒ** in words such as **measure**.
> For example, **delicious** came to English from Latin via the French **délicieux** **de li  sjø**, but in English the **j** coalesced into **ʃ** several centuries ago.

Comment: So that means there is no yod dropping so the words have j when pronounced? But I still don't understand all of the cases when this might happen, since appreciate seems to be different to those, or schedule.

Comment: @otoarno The very idea in coalescing rules out any dropping (as in "pos_t_man"); you must consider that yod is a phonetic entity, not a grapheme: yod is _in_ the pronunciation of the grapheme u, that's what counts (nature, pressure, measure, …).  In the case of "schedule" the question of the difference has nothing to do with assimilation: it is rather a question of greek root; I think that "sch" (skh) is "sk" in Greek, but as the English word comes from the French, and as they chose to pronounce this combination  s, the influence of both the Greek and French is found in the pronounciation.

Answer (score 0):

In English pronunciation is notoriously inconsistent.  Take, for example, '...ough':  we have 'cough' (as in 'off'), 'enough' (as in 'cuff'), 'through' (as in 'true'), 'though' (as in 'throw'), 'thorough' (I cannot think of a word by the 'ough' sounds 'er'; 'thought' as in 'fort'; and probably others I have missed. Yours has to do with the shape of the mouth and palate.

There is an explanation in this case, which has to do with the origin of the word from French and the fact that in English, the letter 'y' is somewhere between a vowel and a consonant.  To say 'tissue' in French the shape of the mouth stays the same except for a small movement of the tip of the tongue downwards, and with the lips slightly more pursed. So the movement is easy (if you are used to it.  The French 'i' in 'tiss' sounds more like English 'teak' than 'tiss', which makes the mouth and tongue move further (uncomfortably) to make the 'you' sound.  So many English (probably a majority) take a sort of short cut by pronouncing the 'ss' as 'sh'.

Pronunciation is a sequence of shapings of mouth, toungue and teeth and follows (in every language and dialect) its own law: follow the line of least resistance as you pass from one syllable to the next.  So as the French word 'tissue', brought to us by the Norman aristocracy in 9th century, found its way in the Anglo-saxon and then English language, its pronunciation morphed.  Just, by the way as the spelling of 'pronunciation' involves the dropping of the 'o' from 'pronounce', similarly following the line of least resistance.  Today, 'tissue' as in 'kiss you' sounds a little old fashioned.

Comment: And also *bough*

Comment: A word pronounced the same as *thorough* is *borough.* Perhaps that's not useful, but I can't actually think of an *-urrer* word which isn't spelled that way.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Kookaburra?

Comment: It's not pronunciation that is inconsistent, it is the -spelling- that has all the problems.

Comment: @Mitch It's a bit of both, of course.  The inconsistency of spelling you mention is the one that tortures children from their early years in primary schools.  You must know the famous example of the craziness of English spelling, uses 'enough'.  The spelling of 'fish' is 'ghoti': 'gh' as pronounced in 'enouGH'; 'o' as pronounced in 'wOmen'; 'ti' as pronounced in 'staTIOn'.